# how to group mysql based on items and today date

Tags: mysql

I have a database that store transaction logs, I would like to count all the logs for that day and group them based on prod_id

MySQL table structure:

Table name = `products`

```
+------+---------+------------+--------+
| ID   | PROD_ID | DATE       | PERSON |
+------+---------+------------+--------+
|    1 |       2 | 1400137633 |      1 |
|    2 |       2 | 1400137666 |      1 |
|    3 |       3 | 1400137125 |      2 |
|    4 |       4 | 1400137563 |      1 |
|    5 |       2 | 1400137425 |      2 |
|    6 |       3 | 1400137336 |      1 |
+------+---------+------------+--------+
```

**MYSQL CODE**:

```
 $q = 'SELECT count(ID) as count 
         FROM PRODUCTS 
        WHERE PERSON ='.$db->qstr($person).' 
          AND DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(DATE)) = DATE(NOW())';
```

so what I get is the number of items for the given date. Since the date is the same as all other entries. however I would like to group the items by prod_id, I tried GROUP BY PROD_ID but that did not give me what I want. I would like it to group if the `PROD_ID` is multiple and the date is the same display as one entry while still count the others

so here I should get an output ($Person = 1).... 2+2+2=1 +3 +4 so total should be 3

any suggestions?

Comment: I unable to understand ur requirement.

Comment: ok, let's say 1400137336 is a Unix time stamp for today. I would like to count all items assigned to me (person) =1 and display the result while grouping multiple items with the same (prod_id) in column PROD_ID to 1, do you understand now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT` with `COUNT` on `PROD_ID`.

**Example**:

```
SELECT count( distinct PROD_ID ) as count 
 FROM PRODUCTS 
 WHERE PERSON = 1  -- <---- change this with relevant variable
   AND DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME (DATE ) ) = curdate();
```

And I suggest you to use `Prepared Statement` to bind values.